# [imodel.js]About the conversion of imodel's geographic coordinate system

Tags: imodeljs

Can an iModel based on the beijing54 geographic coordinate system be converted to another imodel based on the xi’an 80 geographic coordinate system using imodel.js?
I think using IModelConnection.GeoServices seems to support the conversion between WGS84 and NAD27. Does it support conversion between other geographic coordinate systems? If so, how to achieve it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imodeljs does not offer functionality to perform general conversion between geographic coordinate systems yet (other than the basic conversion between the iModel geographic coordinate system and a specified longitude/latitude system based on a designated datum).
For the moment it is recommended that all model data share the same geographic coordinate system.